# managing multiple socket using select()

Tags: c++, sockets, select, winsock

I'm having problem getting select() to work correctly on handling multiple clients and receiving messages from them without blocking on each operation.

I learned that select  determines the status of one or more sockets so each time a connection has been accepted i put socket in the set, using macros it determine which one is ready to read. I observed that my code never enter accept_clients() function.
I'd like if someone look into my code and help to get it work.

Here's my code.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//sockets
#define CLIENT_CON 10
#define CLIENT_DIS 20
#define BF_SZ 100
#define MAX_CONS 5
#define TIMEVAL_SEC 0
#define TIMEVAL_USEC 10
SOCKET sock, clien;
int PR_CONS = 0;

 struct _client
{
    bool con; // Set true if a client is connected
    sockaddr_in addr; // Client info like ip address
    SOCKET cs; // Client socket
    //fd_set set; // used to check if there is data in the socket
    int i; // any piece of additional info
};
_client client[10];
fd_set sset;

 int accept(_client*);
 int recv(_client*, char*, int);
 void Server_Status(int );
 void accept_clients();
 void recv_client();
int main() {
    //int res;
    int i = 1;
    int port = 5150;
    WSADATA ws;
    printf("\t Echo Server (Multiple client support)\n");
    sockaddr_in ser;
    ser.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ser.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    ser.sin_port = htons(port);
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&ws);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    bind(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&ser, sizeof(ser));
    listen(sock,5);
    printf("listening \n");
    unsigned long b= 1;
    ioctlsocket(sock,FIONBIO,&b);

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS; i++) {
        client[i].con = false;
    }
    while(true) {
        accept_clients();
        recv_client();
    }

}
 int accept(_client* x) {
     x->i = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
     int isClient = 0;
     unsigned long b= 1;
     FD_ZERO(&sset);
     FD_SET(sock, &sset);
     isClient = select(0, &sset, NULL,NULL, 0);
     if(isClient > 0 && PR_CONS <  MAX_CONS) {
         x->cs = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&x->addr, &x->i);
         ioctlsocket(x->cs,FIONBIO,&b);
             if(x->cs != INVALID_SOCKET ) {
             x->con = true;
             FD_ZERO(&sset);
             FD_SET(x->cs,&sset);
             return true;
         }
     }
     //printf("failed to accept client");
     return false;
 }

 int recv(_client *x, char* buffer, int sz) {
     int r;
     /*timeval timeOut;
     timeOut.tv_sec = TIMEVAL_SEC;
     timeOut.tv_usec = TIMEVAL_USEC;*/
     r = select(0,&sset, NULL,NULL,0);
    if(r >  0) {
        if((FD_ISSET(x->cs,&sset)) ) {
            x->i = recv(x->cs,buffer,sz, 0);
            if(x->i > 0) {
                Server_Status(CLIENT_DIS);
                FD_CLR(x->cs,&sset);
                return 0;
            }
            return true;
          }
        }
         return false;
 }

 void accept_clients() {
     for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS;  i++) {
         if(!client[i].con) {
            if(accept(&client[i])) {
                Server_Status(CLIENT_CON);
            }
        }
    }
 }
void Server_Status(int msg) {
    if(msg == CLIENT_CON) {
        PR_CONS++;
        printf("client has connected");
    }
    else if(msg == CLIENT_DIS) {
        PR_CONS--;
        printf("client has disconnected");
    }
    else {
        printf("we got unknown message");
    }
}


void recv_client() {
    printf("problem?");
    char buffer[BF_SZ];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONS; i++) {
        if(client[i].con) {
            if(recv(&client[i],buffer, BF_SZ)) {
                std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the first argument of select shouldn't be 0 it should be the number of the maximum fd at least on the linux implementation

Comment: @Tyker winsock is windows based

Comment: `accept_clients` calls `accept` multiple times in a row. Each time, `select()` blocks waiting for new connection to arrive on the listening socket. I presume you do not have `MAX_CONS` clients all attempting to connect, so one of those `select()` calls blocks forever.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so I shoud remove loop in recv_accept and paste code in recv function inside it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried that but didn't help me because I need to loop through each socket to check wheter its ready to receive data, that what FD_ISSET work right? it check specified socket if there is operation on it.

Comment: You should pass to `select()` all the sockets on which you are waiting for something to happen - not one by one. This means the listening socket as well as all client sockets that were previously accepted and not closed yet. When `select()` returns, it will tell you which of those sockets have operations or errors pending - perform those operations/handle those errors, then call `select()` again.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik select(0,&sset, NULL,NULL,0); does that, I put them all on the same socket so select will notify readfds when there is a client trying to connect. I'm not sure how to pass all socket once because select take sets as argument and ISSET take only one socket at time so i can't check them all at once? can you show me using code?

Comment: Every `FD_SET` call is preceded by `FD_ZERO`, so you never have more than one socket in the set when calling `select()`

Answer (score 0):

Unless the number of clients is fixed (always MAX_CONS) clients, and nothing can be exchanged before they are all connected), you are misusing select.

The more common usage is (pseudo code)

```
s = listening_socket
put s in a fd_set
loop on select
   if s is ready for read:
      new_con = accept
      store new_con in a client array
      put s in the fd_set
   else
      find one element of the read-ready set other than s (*)
      recv data from that client
      process data
```

---

(*) you can start from first element, in that case first clients will have a slightly higher priority, or start after last used element and wrap to first after last (round-robin) to give all clients same priority

Comment: from msdn select will notify readfds if "If listen has been called and a connection is pending, accept will succeed. Data is available for reading (includes OOB data if SO_OOBINLINE is enabled). Connection has been closed/reset/terminated." in this case both pending connection and data ready to receive will notify readfds macro, your answer doesn't show how you distinguish each operation what I'm missing here?

Comment: @Dota: *if s is ready for read* should translate in C language as `if (FD_ISSET(s, &rd_set))`

Comment: but s is listening socket it won't be ready to receive data? so to handle data that are ready to receive I need array of socket and loop through each of them to check which client socket is ready to read?

Comment: For a listening socket, "ready to receive" means "ready to accept"